# Linking grid controls with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, grid

I'm new to WPF and C#. I have a grid with rows and columns and one column is dedicated to displaying values obtained from the database rows (textboxes have been put to gather the data). This is the code I have written but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-QTFGN00;Database=VITALS;Integrated Security=True");

static void RetrieveMultipleResults(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Height, Weight FROM dbo.Vitals;", connection);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            textBox.MeasurementGrid = (reader["Weight"].ToString());
            textBox.DataBind();

            textBox_Copy.Text = (reader["Height"].ToString());

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox.Text = (reader["Weight"].ToString());
                textBox_Copy.Text = (reader["Height"].ToString());
            }

            reader.NextResult();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I bind a value that is being read from the database to a particular textbox? E.g. "Weight" from the database needs to be displayed in `textBox` and "Height" in `textBox_Copy` in the MeasurementGrid grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a dataGrid. This controll will take care of generating columns and rows for you.

You can than simply asign a collection of rows to the "ItemsSource" Property of Datagrid.

I also recommend to get used to the Model View ViewModel (MVVM) pattern.

[enter link description here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html)